# Angular 2 - forkJoin can't bind the correct lass

Tags: class, angular, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to do multiple ajax calls together.
I can't figure out what is wrong with these lines. Seems like the second input of the subscribe function is processed as Group[] instead of Authorization[]

```
 Observable.forkJoin(
            [this.userService.getAllGroups(),this.userService.getAllAuthorizations()]
        )
        .subscribe(
            ([groups,authorizations]) => {
                this.groups = groups;
                this.authorizations = authorizations; //error: Type 'Group[]' is not assignable to type 'Authorization[]'
                this.loaderService.hideLoader();
            },
            (err)=>{
                this.loaderService.hideLoader();
            }
        );
```

Interfaces are:

```
(method) UserService.getAllGroups(): Observable<Group[]>
(method) UserService.getAllAuthorizations(): Observable<Authorization[]>
```

Anyone can help me understand what the is problem?

Comment: What is `([groups,authorizations]) =>` supposed to do?

Comment: What does `console.log(groups, authorizations)` print when added as first line in the `subscribe(...)` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```js
Observable.forkJoin<Group[], Authorization[]>(
         this.userService.getAllGroups(),
         this.userService.getAllAuthorizations()
      ).subscribe(results => {
         this.groups = results[0];
         this.authorizations = results[1];
      );
```

or

```js
Observable.forkJoin<Group[], Authorization[]>(
         this.userService.getAllGroups(),
         this.userService.getAllAuthorizations()
      ).subscribe((groups, authorizations) => {
         this.groups = groups;
         this.authorizations = authorizations;
      );
```