# Angular 2 nested observable loop

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable, angular2-observables

I have two observable working against http api.
One is asking for places, the second for events.

The one which asks for events returns a hash of:

```
place_id => events_arr
```

and my code shows

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let place of placesData">
  <ion-item>
    <h1>{{place.name}}</h1>

      <ion-slides>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let event of eventsData[place.id]">
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>{{event.title}}</h1>
          </ion-slide>
        </ng-container>
      </ion-slides>
  </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

My problem is that `placesData` observable is faster than `eventsData` , so `eventsData[place.id]` raises the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '12' of undefined
```

Any idea?

Comment: quick little hack `<ion-slides *ngIf="eventsData">...</ion-slides>` ?

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 would be to use `*ngIf` as @mickdev already pointed via comment.

Option 2 would be to use `forkJoin()`.

```js
Observable.forkJoin(
   yourPlacesFunctionReturningAnObservable(),
   yourEventsFunctionReturningAnObservable())
.subscribe(result => {
   this.placesData = result[0];
   this.eventsData = result[1];
});
```

`forkJoin` will "wait" untill all observables are done.

docs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373283/3631348